# Multiline string annotations for terraform kubernetes provider

Tags: yaml, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I would like to set up [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io) as an API Gateway for kubernetes using terraform. There are several ways how to configure Ambassador. The recommended way, according to [documentation](https://www.getambassador.io/concepts/developers), is by using kubernetes annotations for each service that is routed and exposed outside the cluster. This is done easily using kubernetes yaml configuration:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
        apiVersion: ambassador/v0
        kind:  Mapping
        name:  my_service_mapping
        prefix: /my-service/
        service: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
```

The `getambassador.io/config` field's value starting with `|` suggest it is a multiline string value. How to achieve the same thing using terraform HCL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraform documentation contains a [section](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#strings) about multiline strings using `<<EOF your multiline string EOF`:

```
resource "kubernetes_service" "my-service" {
  "metadata" {
    name = "my-service"
    annotations {
      "getambassador.io/config" = <<EOF
        apiVersion: ambassador/v0
        kind:  Mapping
        name:  my_service_mapping
        prefix: /my-service/
        service: my-service
        EOF
    }
  }
  "spec" {
    selector {
      app = "MyApp"
    }
    port {
      protocol = "TCP"
      port = 80
      target_port = "9376"
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure there is no triple dash (`---`) from yaml configuration. Terraform parses it incorrectly.

Comment: Will this work with the helm provider?